# Attempts to unbind event handler that is in $.proxy and is a prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery

In an object's prototype, I have

```
obj.prototype.function1 = function(){
    $(window).on("scroll",$.proxy(this.trigger,this));
}
```

In another prototype, I have

```
obj.prototype.function2 = function(){
     $(window).off("scroll",this.trigger);
}
```

But `$(window).off("scroll",this.trigger);` is not unbinding `this.trigger`.

Therefore, I tried making `$.proxy(this.trigger,this)` as property of `obj` in `function1`:

```
this.triggery = $.proxy(this.trigger,this);
```

and turning it off in `function2`:

```
$(window).off("scroll",this.triggery);
```

But it still can't be `.off`-ed;

How should I unbind an eventhandler like this?

P.S. *I've tried using the conventional `.bind` and `.unbind` but to no avail.*

Comment: The second approach should work. Can you make a complete example how you are calling this?

Comment: @Bergi Thanks! You are right! I've just checked with my design model and realized there was something wrong with it, but not with the binding & unbinding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. There isn't anything wrong with the binding & unbinding. The problem lies on my design pattern. I accidentally called `.on` again right after `.off` (I've only discovered it after console.logging). Thanks Bergi again for letting me know that the second is actually the right way of unbinding it!

```
this.triggery = $.proxy(this.trigger,this);
```